# Calculator code problems: 10 + 5 results in 105

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to this forum and new to python after c++.

I have a problem with a python calculator. When I run it and I do it with `+` for example : `10 + 5` gives `105`, but I wanted to get `15`.

Other operations don't even work (I get an error).

```
print("\nCalculator In Python")
print("\nChose The Operation :")
print("\na)+\n\nb)-\n\nc)/\n\nd)*")
answer = input("\n\n: ")
result = int

if answer == 'a':
    a = input("\n\nFirst Number : ")
    b = input("\n\nSecond Number : ")
    print(a, "+", b, "=", a+b)
elif answer == 'b':
    a = input("\n\nFirst Number : ")
    b = input("\n\nSecond Number : ")
    print(a, "-", b, "=", a-b)
elif answer == 'c':
    a = input("\n\nFirst Number : ")
    b = input("\n\nSecond Number : ")
    print(a, "/", b, "=", a/b)
elif answer == 'd':
    a = input("\n\nFirst Number : ")
    b = input("\n\nSecond Number : ")
    print(a, "*", b, "=", a*a)
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28393146/4354477)

Answer (score 3):

`a+b` is actually `'10'+'5'`, which is `'105'`. This is happening because 
`input()` gives a string. So you need to convert it to a number first.

```
float(input())
```

---

Additionally, to ensure the user gives only valid numbers, you can use:

```
while True:
    a = input('\nGive a:')

    try:
        a = float(a)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Try again.')
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'input' functions return a string that contains "10" and "5". Conducting a + operator on two strings concatenates them (i.e. "10" + "5" = "105").

If you convert the input to an float or integer you'll get the result you're looking for:

```
>>> a = "5" + "5"
>>> a
'55'
>>> 
>>> b = float("5") + float("5")
>>> b
10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is setting your input to strings. 
You could check this with the "type(a)" function.

You would need to convert the input to either a float or integer.

```
integer = int(a)
FloatingPoint = float(a)
```